# How to make CoordinatorLayout children to be static in phone screen?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I have this kind of activity structure, where FrameLayout is filled in child Activities of my NavigationDrawerActivity (extent of AppCompatActivity). I have problem in collapsing Toolbar. When toolbar extended, bottom childs of FrameLayout are being pushed form the screen (chat input card or etc.). Is there is any way to cleanly determine children static and unmovable in screen?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_linear"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If i set app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" only on FrameLayout children (RecycleView) , hide event dose not work.